# AddHttpClient in Blazor Server Side

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create an httpclient in Blazor Server side which would create the least amount of configuration effort every time I call my webapi.

Essentially I would like achieve the following:

1. Named HTTPClient I can automatically call when I call a function in my webapi.
2. The webapi requires a bearer token, which I get by calling AcquireTokenSilent
3. Would be great if I don't have to specify the httpclient when I call the api
4. The webapi has been added as a service reference, so there is scaffold classes created under the namespace myapp.server.api

To start this off, I created the following in startup:

```
services.AddHttpClient<myapp.server.api.swaggerClient>(c =>
        {
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapp.com/");

            AzureADB2COptions opt = new AzureADB2COptions();
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", opt);

            IConfidentialClientApplication cca =
            ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(opt.ClientId)
            .WithRedirectUri(opt.RedirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(opt.ClientSecret)
            .WithB2CAuthority(opt.Authority)
            .WithClientName("myWebapp")
            .WithClientVersion("0.0.0.1")
            .Build();

            IHttpContextAccessor pp;
            string signedInUserID = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            new MSALStaticCache(signedInUserID, pp.HttpContext).EnablePersistence(cca.UserTokenCache);

            var accounts = cca.GetAccountsAsync().Result;
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            result = cca.AcquireTokenSilent(opt.ApiScopes.Split(' '), accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync().Result;

            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);


        });
```

My hope is to be able to call my api in my views in this way:

```
 myapp.server.api.swaggerClient t = new myapp.server.api.swaggerClient();
 currentCount = t.WeatherForecastAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault().Summary;
```

calling a new instance of swaggerclient requires me to specify an httpclient, so my hopes is to inject the httpclient I am configuring on a global level for that type can be injected automatically.

The pieces I need help with:

1. Given that I have specified my httpclient scoped to a specific type, would it call automatically if I call a function in my webapi? (Does not seem to fire when debugging)
2. To get the bearer token, I need to get the current userID, which is in the authstateprovider... seeing that this is in Startup, is getting it from DI even possible?
3. Any easy way to inject the httpclient on the constructor of my webapi classes?  would I be able to get the httpclient in the constructor so that I essentially have a parameterless constructor not asking for httpclient?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first question, inject the Web API HttpClient like this in your view:

```
@inject myapp.server.api.swaggerClient MyClient
```

and then in the code block:

```
currentCount = MyClient.WeatherForecastAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault().Summary;
```

You should be able to debug the code inside `AddHttpClient`.